# PHP input to JSON file and JSON file to PHP output

Tags: php, json

Can anyone please shows me how to get the input of PHP to JSON file (.json) and read data from JSON file and display in PHP (Echo).

for example:

```
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age= 20;
```

to `result.json`

```
{"name":"John","Age":20}
```

and retrieve from `result.json` and display data in PHP as

```
name=John
Age=20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the object to json use this:

```
$json = json_encode($myObj);
```

See the [json_encode docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

To return it back to the format you want try this...

```
$obj = json_decode($json);

$name = $obj->name;  // John
$age = $obj->age; // 20
```

See the [json_decode docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

To iterate over keys and values do something like this:

```
foreach($obj as $key=>$value)
{

    echo $key . " = " . $value . "\n";

}
```

Comment: what if i want to know the keys values such as Name and age ?

Answer (score 0):

**json_encode()** is used for encoding PHP data into a JSON format and **json_decode()** is used to decode JSON into a PHP data

**json_encode** documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**json_decode** documentation 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

if you are having an php array you can convert it into json.

```
$json_string = json_encode($array);
```

and write this into a json file.

```
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_string);
fclose($fp);
```

now convert your json string which is in results.json to array.

```
$str = file_get_contents('./results.json');
$array = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
```